# How do I map OAuth 2 token to UserDetails object in a resource server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I have 2 separate Spring Boot applications, one serving as an an OAuth 2 authorization server, and the other as resource server. I'm using Spring's `RemoteTokenServices` in my resource server to check tokens from the authorization server. Now, I'm trying to define protected controller code in my resource server application, but I'm not sure how to map the `UserDetails` class to the authentication principal provided through the OAuth 2 mechanism.

I have set up my authorization server with a custom `TokenEnhancer` that adds more details to the token such that `/oauth/check_token?token=<token>` returns with custom fields, which I want to map to my resource server controllers.

In a more monolithic setup where the authorization server is also the resource server, I can define controller methods that make use of the authenticated principal this way:

```
//User implements UserDetails
public Map<String, Object> getResource(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    //code that uses the user object
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as straight forward in a more distributed approach. The mapping fails, and the `user` parameter ends up being a null object. I tried using the following approach:

```
public Map<String, Object> getResource(Authentication authentication) {
    //code that uses the authentication object
}
```

While the code above successfully maps the authentication details, it doesn't provide a way for me to directly access the custom fields I've set through the `TokenEnhancer` I mentioned earlier. I can't seem to find anything from the Spring docs regarding this.

Comment: may be you can fetch user from database or something using your detail service and userid

Comment: I have as same as your problem, would you put your complete configuration

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To resolve the issue, let me go through a bit of architectural background first. The `UserDetails` object automatically mapped through the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` comes from the `principal` field of the active `Authentication` object. A resource server controller has access to an `OAuth2Authencation` object, which is a specialized instance of `Authentication` for Spring OAuth2 security framework, just by simply declaring it as part of the method parameters.

```
public void controllerMethod(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    //controller definition
}
```

Knowing this, the problem now shifts to how to make sure that the `getPrincipal()` method in the `Authentication` object is an instance of my custom `UserDetails` class. The `RemoteTokenServices` I use in the resource server application uses an instance of `AccessTokenConverter` to interpret token details sent by the authorization server. By default, it uses `DefaultAccessTokenConverter`, which just sets the authentication principal as the username, which is a `String`. This converter makes use of `UserAuthenticationConverter` to convert the data coming from the authorization server into an instance of `Authentication`. This is what I needed to customize:

```
DefaultAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
tokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter() {

    @Override
    public Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        Authentication authentication = super.extractAuthentication(map);
        // User is my custom UserDetails class
        User user = new User();
        user.setSpecialKey(map.get("specialKey").toString());
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                authentication.getCredentials(), authentication.getAuthorities());
    }

});
tokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(tokenConverter);
```

With all these set up, the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` mechanism now works as expected.

Comment: This solution works, but it's more of a workaround rather than a fix. The reason you get String for Principle is because the userDetailsService is not injected properly into DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter(). Now the question is where does it need to be injected so that this workaround is not required?

Comment: Do you have answer for that question? This does not seem to be documented anywhere

Comment: You could also directly inject your Custom Implementation of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService like this:
JwtAccessTokenConverter jwt = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter duac = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
duac.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
DefaultAccessTokenConverter datc = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
datc.setUserTokenConverter(duac);
jwt.setAccessTokenConverter(datc);

Comment: Would you put the complete source code of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`, like following xml?

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And you need to implement the `UserDetails` to return your own `CustomerUser object`, then you can use the annotation to get principal directly.

Comment: I've never had to define that explicitly. I think that resolver is already part of Spring Boot's auto-configuration.

Comment: @PsychoPunch It is.