# How to get OAuth2AccessToken in Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I have a resource server application for which I want to define a controller that needs to get hold of additional information from `OAuth2AccessToken`. The additional information in the token are added using the authorization server's `TokenEnhancer`. However, I'm not really sure which part of the whole Spring OAuth 2 configuration I can use for this. I'm using a `RemoteTokenServices` in my application, which provides a `readAccessToken` method. However, when I try to use it, I get `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: What information specifically are you needing? What does the enhancement look like?

Comment: I've added a few user-related details in the token, like UUID, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason not to grab that off of the `@AuthenticationPrincipal`?

Comment: The `AuthenticationPrincipal` is an instance of `UserDetails`, which does not have the extra details I need. I actually also have a [different issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086182/how-do-i-map-oauth-2-token-to-userdetails-object-in-a-resource-server) mapping the `AuthenticationPrincipal` to my custom `UserDetails` class.